# How to get proper gradient map?

Tags: materials, shader-nodes

I am trying to get this kind of gradient map.

[image]

I am getting this:

[image]

And I want to control the falloff and intensity of the gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a setup like this - don't forget to change your *View Transform* from *Filmic* to *Standard* (right side) so the whites and blacks show up properly. Also, notice I used "Ease" (as opposed to Linear) for the ColorRamp interpolation as it gives a "softer" falloff:

[image: Grad]

Answer (score 2):

Your gradient is using generated coordinates, so it's making a gradient from the bounding box of the object.  But it looks like you want a gradient made from the bounding boxes of *multiple* objects.

There are a number of ways to do this.  One thing I'll sometimes do is make a custom bounding box for multiple objects:

[image]

By creating an artificial bounding box around all of my objects, I can use that, in conjunction with project from view (bounds) unwrapping, to create a consistent UV mapping of the objects, by projecting UV on all objects at once.  Then, I can use those UV coordinates, as shown, to feed the vector for my gradient texture.

If you want this to be dynamic, one way would be to instance multiple objects using geometry nodes, realizing instances and assigning your material; these objects would then have generated coordinates that represented their appropriate, grouped bounding box.

Another technique would be to use an object that scaled to encompass the bounding box of all objects.  You could shrinkwrap objects or bones, from distant positions, onto the meshes, and then measure the distances between those objects, using stretch-to constraints or drivers.  This could be used to scale an object from which you could use object coordinates.  It's probably too complicated for the task at hand though.